# Pandas: Time-weighted rolling average on ragged time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I have a ragged (meaning not-a-regular frequency), time-indexed DataFrame, that I would like to perform a time-weighted rolling average on, that maintains the original index of the DataFrame. It is assumed that a recorded value is valid until superseded by another value. One way to achieve this is by just up-sampling the the ragged DataFrame to a uniform frequency and then do a rolling mean:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def time_weighted_average_using_upsampling(df: pd.DataFrame, avg_window: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Leads to high memory usage
    original_index = df.index.copy()
    avg = (
        df.resample("1s")
        .ffill()
        .rolling(avg_window, closed="left", min_periods=int(avg_window[0])))
        .mean()
        .reindex(original_index)
    )
    return avg


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {"A": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
        index=[
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:00"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:02"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:03"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:05"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:06"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:10"),
        ],
    )

    expected_avg = pd.DataFrame(
        {"A": [np.nan, np.nan, 1 / 3, 5 / 3, 7 / 3, 4]},
        index=[
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:00"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:02"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:03"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:05"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:06"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:10"),
        ],
    )

    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(
        time_weighted_average_using_upsampling(df=df, avg_window="3s"), expected_avg
    )
```

The issue with this is that the up-sampling defeats the purpose of the sparse representation that the ragged df offers. A sparse representation is memory efficient, while the up-sampled version is not. This begs the question: How does one achieve the result shown above *without* having to up-sample the entire df?

Comment: This is an interesting question, if your problem is to not upsample the the full dataframe at once, then maybe you can consider upsampling only the last 3 rows and do the calculation like `df.rolling(3, closed='left').apply(lambda x: x.resample("1s").ffill()[-4:-1].mean())` but this won't be really efficient I guess because you perform many upsampling at the end

Comment: I thought about that approach as well. It would deal with memory constraints, but there are practical challenges, one of which I don't see how to solve. `df.rolling().apply()` does not give the callable anything but an array of samples, hence you cannot use df operations.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand when you say array, but `df.rolling().apply()` does pass a Series into it, not an numpy array now. the parameter [raw has been added in v0.23](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.23.0.html#rolling-expanding-apply-accepts-raw-false-to-pass-a-series-to-the-function), it seems it was set to True by default in this earlier version, but since it seems that the default is [False](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) that passes a Serie, hence the index is available

Comment: You are absolutely right! My mistake. I used a slightly older version of pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions inspired by @Ben.T:

```py
def time_weighted_average_using_local_upsampling(df: pd.DataFrame, avg_window: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Uses second resolution up-sampling only on smaller windows at a time."""
    original_index = df.index.copy()
    avg = (
        df.reindex(df.index.union(df.index.shift(periods=-1, freq=avg_window)), method="ffill")
        .rolling(avg_window, closed="both", min_periods=2)
        .apply(lambda x: x.resample("1s").ffill()[:-1].mean(skipna=False))
        .reindex(original_index)
    )
    return avg


def time_weighted_average_using_index_weighting(df: pd.DataFrame, avg_window: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Uses weighting by duration, by ensuring every window has a point at the start."""
    original_index = df.index.copy()
    avg = (
        df.reindex(df.index.union(df.index.shift(periods=-1, freq=avg_window)), method="ffill")
        .rolling(avg_window, closed="both", min_periods=2)
        .apply(lambda x: np.average(x[:-1], weights=x.index.to_series().diff()[1:].dt.seconds))
        .reindex(original_index)
    )
    return avg
```

The first one up-samples single rolling windows at a time, while the latter actually does ragged time weighted averaging, by ensuring that there is always a point available at the start of the windows we care about. This is done by including the original index shifted by the window length.

I have yet to measure performance on relevant cases.

**EDIT:**
I decided to test the functions on a second resolution dataset with around 100,000 rows, and using 20 minute windows(!) Both variants were unbearably slow, but I think I have a new winner:

```py
def time_weighted_average_using_index_weighting2(df: pd.DataFrame, avg_window: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Uses weighting by duration, by ensuring every window has a point at the start."""
    original_index = df.index.copy()
    avg = df.reindex(df.index.union(df.index.shift(periods=-1, freq=avg_window)), method="ffill")
    avg = (
        avg.multiply(avg.index.to_series().diff().dt.seconds.shift(-1), axis=0)
        .divide(pd.Timedelta(avg_window).seconds)
        .rolling(avg_window, closed="left")
        .sum()
        .reindex(original_index)
    )
    avg[~((avg.index - pd.Timedelta(avg_window)) >= original_index[0])] = np.nan
    return avg
```

This one does the weighting up front, before rolling, and hence we get away with using `.sum()` instead of `apply()`. This translates to an enormous speed increase. We also get away with at most a doubling of indexes, regardless of the size of the averaging window.

Comment: interesting, I'll give it a try when I have time :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative, instead of upsampling the whole dataframe, you can first check where the time diff between 2 rows are bigger than the gap. then remove 3s to the rows with the gap and `reindex` df with union of these specific new timestamps. Once these rows created, you can `groupby` using where you added the new indexes, `resample` 1s per group and finally `rolling` with the method you did. `Reindex` with df at the end.

```
rule = 3
rolling_win = f'{rule}s'

sparse = df.index.to_series().diff().dt.total_seconds().ge(rule)
new_timestamps = df.index[sparse] - pd.Timedelta(seconds=rule)
print(new_timestamps) 
#DatetimeIndex(['2013-01-01 09:00:07'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

#reindex with the new 
df_ = df.reindex(df.index.union(new_timestamps))

#perform first the resample 1s per group, then clean the dataframe to do the rolling.mean
#finally reindex like original df
df_ = (df_.groupby(df_.index.isin(new_timestamps).cumsum())
          .resample("1s").ffill()
          .reset_index(level=0, drop=True).ffill()
          .rolling(rolling_win, closed="left", min_periods=rule)\
          .mean()
          .reindex(df.index)
      )
print(df_)
                            A
2013-01-01 09:00:00       NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:02       NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:03  0.333333
2013-01-01 09:00:05  1.666667
2013-01-01 09:00:06  2.333333
2013-01-01 09:00:10  4.000000
```

In this case it is not really interesting because the gap is actually small, but if the gap are huge, then it becomes useful.

EDIT or another option, probably better, `union` all the index made from the original index that you remove 1s, 2s, 3s,... (depending on the rule). Now you have only necessary index for the rolling so `reindex`, `ffill` and `rolling.mean`. Same result at the end

```
from functools import reduce

rule = 3
rolling_win = f'{rule}s'

idx = df.index
df_ = (df.reindex(reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), 
                         [idx - pd.Timedelta(seconds=i) 
                          for i in range(0, rule+1)]))
         .ffill()
         .rolling(rolling_win, closed="left", min_periods=rule)\
         .mean()
         .reindex(df.index)
        )
```

Comment: Another approach I developed based on your comments from yesterday:
```python
def time_weighted_average_using_local_upsampling(df: pd.DataFrame, avg_window: str) -> pd.DataFrame:

    original_index = df.index.copy()
    avg = (
        df.reindex(df.index.union(df.index.shift(periods=-1, freq=avg_window)), method="ffill")
        .rolling(avg_window, closed="both", min_periods=2)
        .apply(lambda x: x.resample("1s").ffill()[:-1].mean(skipna=False))
        .reindex(original_index)
    )
    return avg
```